# Can we make a JSF Application be a Web Service Server? And if it is possible, how is this actually done?

Tags: java, web-services, jsf-2

I am new to JSF and, I need to make my JSF Application to be a web service server. Is this possible? And, if it is, can you please help me how to do it?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? If you have JSF you have regular Servlets as well that will pose better as Web Service Providers that the visual oriented JSF

Comment: Hi @Angelo Neuschitzer, 
First of all, thank you for your response. 
It is because, I have a 2nd web application that needs to open my JSF application's modify page once I clicked an edit link from my 2nd web app. And, this web app. will pass 2 parameters to my JSF application.

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from using Servlets in your JSF-enabled web application. Heck - JSF itself does most of its magic through a servlet.

Comment: @Des You should use a Servlet that accepts the two parameters and performs the modify action (or whatever you want to do with it). While you theoretically could somehow work your way through JSF to achieve this, is is with next to 100% a BAD IDEA. Don't do it. Write a Servlet that reads two parameters from your request and performs the action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Please keep in mind that this is a `BAD IDEA` anyway, so the answer will look like one as well)

Create a `form` with `JSF`. As soon as it works as expected use your second web app to `GET` the form `HTML` code, parse it and `POST` your parameters with the `form`.

If you created your `JSF` form well enough it will be sufficiently consistent that you can skip the `GET` and directly use the `POST`.

You could also use some third-party library to do the parsing and filling of the `form` for you. (But that does not make the idea any better)

Before you do that read about `RESTful`, `JSON` and most importanly `Servlet`. What they do, when to use them and realize that your approach is most likely not going to produce good, reliable, maintainable code.

**DON'T DO IT THIS WAY** (Unless you really REALLY understood what you are doing there)